# Where does the extra wire connect on my new furnace blower motor?

Tags: hvac

My furnace is approximately 20+ years old and i need to replace the blower motor.  however the replacement has six wires and the existing has 5.

Here's the existing motor's wiring diagram:
[image: Original motor name plate]

And here's the replacement's:
[image: Replacement motor name plate]

I understand the brown wires will connect to the capacitor, and the red, black, and blue wires controls speed. What I do know is what the  white connects to (it’s the wiring between the capacitor and the speed controls). There is a green wire for grounding.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was using my phone to provide the info.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the grey colored motor is the new one and the rusty one is the old. In your old configuration the capacitor connected between the AC neutral (white) and the brown wire. In your new motor the white still needs to connect to your AC neutral. However, your new motor has two brown wires to connect to the capacitor, and any connection between it and AC common (if it has one) is internal to the motor. So whatever the white wire connected to on your old motor is where the white wire on your new motor should connect to. (I'm not sure if the diagram indicates that the wire in question is white, purple, or yellow; or a wire with white, purple, and yellow stripes. Your pictures don't show the actual wires.)

Comment: It’s a white wire. So does that mean I’ll have 2 brown wires, 1 white wire and 1 black wire in the capacitor, or would it be brown, white, on one side (although the diagram shows both brown wires going to the capacitor), and black on the other side?The existing wire configuration was 2 white on one side and a black on the opposite side

Comment: Yes, you will have two brown wires going to the capacitor, and the three speed control wires going to the same connectors as the old motor. The black wire is one of the speed control wires. It does not connect to the capacitor.