# Changing blower motors with different wiring schemes

Tags: wiring, blower, motor

My blower motor crapped out and I got a basically new, used one for cheap but only realized after the fact that they were wired differently.  Basically I'm attempting the opposite of this previous post:

[Where does the extra wire connect on my new furnace blower motor?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/125282/where-does-the-extra-wire-connect-on-my-new-furnace-blower-motor)

My old motor had black, yellow, and blue wires for high, medium, and low speed, an orange common wire, and two purple wires to connect to the capacitor.  The new motor has black, blue, and red wires for high, medium, and low speed, and a brown and purple wire to connect to the capacitor.  On the wiring diagram the purple wire from the capacitor is shown completing a circuit with the black wire.  So do I need to connect a jumper from the leg of the capacitor the purple wire connects to with the orange common wire connection on my air handler?

Old motor P/N: Lennox 34K7601, Emerson K55HXEKD-7375

New motor P/N: Goodman 0131M00005P, Zhongshan Broad-Ocean YDK-250S63223-02

[image: 0131M00005P YDK-250S63223 wiring diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On the wiring diagram the purple wire from the capacitor is shown completing a circuit with the black wire.

No, that's not what the diagram says.  If they required you to jumper that, they would give instructions to that effect and the diagram would be clearer.

The graphic is indicating which two wires are the LINE (supply) wires.  They are saying "This one is... and that one is". That's why the lines are dotted.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't trying to suggest jumpering the two wires together when I mentioned completing a circuit, I could have phrased that better.  My question was if this motor is intended to have the purple leg of the capacitor connected to the common wire on the air handler wire harness?  Your comment stating these are being called out as line (supply) wires is in line with my interpretation, but I just wanted to make sure before flipping the breaker.

Update, I did connect the purple leg of the capacitor to my common wire on the air handler wire harness and the motor fires up and runs OK.